# wait for python script to run from node js

Tags: python, node.js

I'm new to node js,

I call my python script from node, and I want to wait until the python script over.
what is the simplest way?
my code :

```
    PythonShell.run('public/python/dag.py', null, function (err,result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result)
       
      })        
      
      console.log("amit")
```

my output:

```
"amit"
["hey python"]
```

expected output:

```
["hey python"]
"amit"
```

Comment: You're missing the basics of async JS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

You see this output because node executes tasks asynchronously.

What you could instead do is have a function that returns a Promise containing the python part and `await` that function before you go to the next part.

Something like this should work:

```
function runpythoncode(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    PythonShell.run('public/python/dag.py', null, function (err,result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      resolve();
    })
  })
}
 
await runpythoncode();

console.log('amit')
```

Comment: thank you! I got this error : "await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"

Comment: Whats the version of node that you using ?